# Keyboard shortcut for switching input language at login screen

Tags: keyboard, macos, language

I've assigned a keyboard shortcut to switch between input languages:

[image: Keyboard settings window]

But this shortcut doesn't work at the login screen. So when I resume from sleep, I have to use the mouse to change input language.

Is there a way to switch between input languages via the keyboard from the logon screen?

Comment: I do not understand, you have two key board short cuts showing. One is forward the other is back to previous source. Please enable both and use to switch Input sources using keyboard. No mouse required.

Comment: "Select next" works in a cyclic way. I only have 2 languages I switch between, so it effectively works as a toggle. E.g. If I'm on lang1 then press the "next" shortcut, it changes to lang2. If I press the "next" shortcut again, it goes back to lang1.

Really, though, that's all beside the point since neither of these shortcuts works in the logon screen.

Comment: OK, thanks! I think? So you do not need the Mouse for that as you said. As for switching the language before you logged in is not possible, and the only text input source is the password. After log in does it not default to last used anyway?

Comment: Sorry if I'm being somehow unclear. The keyboard shortcut works fine after login. The point of my question is that the shortcut does not work on the login screen.

Comment: We are talking about the INPUT source. There is no input on log in screen other than password. You can not switch the Input source in the log in screen.

Comment: Yes you can: http://i.imgur.com/ytf28NG.jpg

Comment: Well, I learned something :)

Comment: I send now feedback error report to Apple, we will see.